# How to use SVG sprite as CSS pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use SVG icons (located in a SVG sprite) as CSS pseudo elements. They're working well in HTML, but when I import them in my CSS nothing is appearing. Where could be the problem?

Working HTML:

```
<svg width="48px" height="48px">
    <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icons-sprite.svg#icon-name"></use>
</svg>
```

SVG sprite:

```
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="icon-name">
        <path ... fill="currentColor"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.test-icon:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url(/assets/images/icons-sprite.svg#icon-name);
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT: I made a GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/JulSeb42/icon-sprite), normally it should always be the same icon in red

Comment: Please read this article: https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/

Comment: Yes I tried this solution, and I see that all icons are just on top of each other when I try it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='48px' height='48px'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='/assets/images/icons-sprite.svg%23icon-name'%3E%3C/use%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Follow this link and paste your svg link. You can get your code for background-image property. https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

Comment: Nope, still the same problem. I see that it appears in the code when I inspect the div, but nothing appears

Comment: I checked this tool, but when I paste it even the preview is empty...

Comment: I used a tool to generate the sprite (since I have more than 500 icons), but apparently the bug came from there. I tried again to generate it with Icomoon this time and it works in CSS. Except that now I can't change the color of the icons, and the HTML does not work anymore

Comment: I made a GitHub repo, it's easier this way https://github.com/JulSeb42/icon-sprite